# RandomizedSearchCV in parallel: Too many dispatched jobs causing NaN loss?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, hyperparameters

Just a heads up: I'm fairly new to the worlds of both machine learning and parallel computing. I'll do my best to use the right terminology, but friendly corrections would be much appreciated.

I've been trying to tune hyperparameters for a Keras MLP (running on top of TensorFlow) by using sklearn's RandomizedSearchCV, wrapping my model in KerasClassifier as per numerous tutorials. I've been trying to parallelize this process via RandomizedSearchCV's built-in system for this. This was working more or less fine, but then when I started using around 6 threads the program would still run, but I would start getting NaN losses, which would lead to errors after the search had concluded.

Now, I know there are a bunch of usual suspects for gradient blow-ups, but there was something interesting here: **this problem went away when I reduced `pre_dispatch` sufficiently** (in this case down to `n_jobs` instead of `2*n_jobs`).

Is there any reason why this would happen? My datasets are pretty large, but it seems that once the searching begins, each job is only using about 1-2% of available memory (also, this percent does not change when I cut the pre-dispatched jobs?), and I'm not getting any other memory use issues.

Secondly, on a more practical note, is there any easy way to get my code to break in RandomSearchCV as soon as an NaN loss comes up? It would save some time as opposed to letting it keep running until the end of the search--which, when fully implemented, will probably take a day or more--and then throw the error. I was also thinking of changing `error_score` to -1 or something. Would this actually be better? I think it is probably worth knowing that certain combinations of hyperparameters lead to gradient blow-ups, but not if its only because of this parallelization issue.

Comment: try putting `error_score='raise'` inside `RandomSearchCV`...it has a bad habit of suppressing errors and returning NaN instead